# Hypergeometric Function near z = 1

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, hypergeometric-function

I know that value of hypergeometric function at $z = 1$ is given by
$$
F(a,b;c;1) = \frac{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c - a - b)}{\Gamma(c - a)\Gamma(c - b)},
$$
(according to the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4)) when $\Re(c) > \Re(a + b)$.

**My question**: is there an expansion (again assuming that $\Re(c) > \Re(a + b)$) for $F(a,b;c;z)$ in possibly non-integer powers of $z-1$ which has $F(a,b;c;1)$ as the first term?
 Also if an expansion like this exists what are the first few terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hypergeometric differential equation with $F(a,b,c,z)$ as a solution near $z=0$ also has solutions at the other two singluar points, $z=1$ and $\infty$.  The function $F(a,b,c,z)$ near $z=1$ is a solution of that DE, so we can write all solutions of it as linear combinations of the two hypergeometric solutions
$$
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,a+b+1-c;\,1-z)},
\\
\left( 1-z \right) ^{c-a-b}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(c-b,c-a;\,1+c-a-b;\,1-z)}.
\tag1$$

The coefficients to use (the "connection coefficients") for your question were worked out by Gauss (or perhaps Goursat?)

Here it is.
\begin{align}
{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,c;\,z)}&={\frac {\Gamma \left( c \right) \Gamma
 \left( c-a-b \right) {\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(a,b;\,a+b+1-c;\,1-z)}}{\Gamma
 \left( c-a \right) \Gamma \left( c-b \right) }}
\\\qquad &+{\frac {\Gamma
 \left( c \right) \Gamma \left( a+b-c \right)  \left( 1-z \right) ^{c-
a-b}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(c-b,c-a;\,1+c-a-b;\,1-z)}}{\Gamma \left( a
 \right) \Gamma \left( b \right) }}
\end{align}

This is for almost all $a,b,c$ not nonpositive integers.  Exceptional cases may occur when $a+b-c \in \mathbb Z$; then the second solution may behave logarithmically near $z=1$.  (See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/184825/454) .)

**Reference.**  Corollary 2.3.3 in

*Andrews, George E.; Askey, Richard; Roy, Ranjan*, [**Special functions**](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22#vi.p1), Encyclopedia of Mathematics and Its Applications. 71. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. xvi, 664 p. (1999). [ZBL0920.33001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0920.33001).

Comment: Note, in general: non-integer powers on $(1-z)$ in the second term.