Derivatives of the hypergeometric functions
I have the equation
\begin{equation}\label{equat}
   \Psi-4 \left(t^2-1\right) \ddot{\Psi} =0 .
\end{equation}
In the region $t\in [-1,1]$ there are the real independent solutions
\begin{align} \label{funcin1}
  g_1(t) & = \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right),-\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right);\frac{1}{2};t^2\right) \\ \label{funcin2}
  g_2(t) & = t\, \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right);\frac{3}{2};t^2\right).
\end{align}
I form the linear combination
\begin{equation}
  \Psi_1 = A g_1 + B g_2,
\end{equation}
with $A$, $B$ being some given constants.
In the region outside $t\in (-\infty,-1) \cup (1,+\infty)$ the solution can be written in terms of the real (in that region) functions
\begin{align} \label{funcout1}
  f_1(t) & = \left(t^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right)} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right);1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};\frac{1}{t^2}\right) \\ \label{funcout2}
  f_2(t) & = \left(t^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(-\sqrt{2}-1\right),\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right);1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}};\frac{1}{t^2}\right).
\end{align}
I want to form a linear combination
\begin{equation}
  \Psi_2 = C f_1 + D f_2,
\end{equation}
choosing the $C$, $D$ so that the solution and its first derivative are continuous at $t=1$, i.e.
\begin{align}
  \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1^{-}} \Psi_1 = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1^{+}} \Psi_2 \\ \label{condition2}
  \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1^{-}} \dot{\Psi}_1 = \lim\limits_{t\rightarrow 1^{+}} \dot{\Psi}_2 .
\end{align}
The first condition is fine, but in the second there is a problem when calculating the derivatives of the hypergeometric functions at that point. According to this site, the derivative of a hypergeometric function can be given in terms of another function of this type
\begin{equation}\label{derhyp}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} _2F_1 (a,b;c;z) = \frac{a b}{c}\, {}_2F_1 (a+1,b+1;c+1;z).
\end{equation}
However, for the functions of our case
\begin{equation}
  c+1 =(a+1)+(b+1) ,
\end{equation}
which (see this link) means that for the function $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} _2F_1 (a,b;c;z)$ the series does not converge at $z=1$. With Mathematica it can be checked that all four derivatives of $g_1$, $g_2$ and $f_1$, $f_1$ diverge to infinity at $t=\pm 1$. As a result, I cannot obtain a condition for the linear combinations involving the constants $C$ and $D$ from the equation for the continuity of the derivatives.

In that DE, we have $t=1$ is a singular point.  There is no reason to think solutions are regular at $t=1$.  (Similarly for $t=-1$.)
In fact, one solution is regular at $t=1$, but all the others have logarithmic singularity there.  We can see this using Frobenius' method of series solutions applied at $t=1$.
\begin{align}
\Psi \left( t \right) &=
C_1\, \left( t-1 \right)  \left( (1+{\frac{
1}{16}} \left( t-1 \right) +O \left(  \left( t-1 \right) ^{2} \right) 
) \right) 
\\&+C_2\, \left( \ln  \left( t-1 \right)  \left( ({\frac
{1}{8}} \left( t-1 \right) +O \left(  \left( t-1 \right) ^{2} \right) 
) \right) +(1+O \left(  \left( t-1 \right) ^{2} \right) ) \right) 
\end{align}

So we have
$$
\lim_{t\to 1} \Psi(t) = C_2
$$
but
$$
\Psi'(t) \sim \log(t-1) \to \pm \infty
$$
unless $C_2 = 0$.

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730424/442 and especially https://mathoverflow.net/q/184825/454

The functions have finite non-zero value at t=1 (check on Mathematica). See also DLMF: §15.2 Definitions and Analytical Properties ‣ Properties ‣ Chapter 15 Hypergeometric Function (nist.gov)
There it is written that, if for the parameters you have c-a-b >0, then the function (F(a,b;c;z)) is convergent in the circle |z|=1. All four solutions of the differential equation have c-a-b=1>0. Their derivatives however have the parameters c-a-b=0, which makes them problematic at the same point.
